# Extracting relevant info from a text string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have bunch of text strings with the following text format:

```
b' ABC Singapore Pte Ltd\n SG-Singapore - Co-Load\n No 30, Carta Avenue\n #01-06 and 02-06\n 4981 SINGAPORE    \n Singapore  \n Tel : +65 1234 56778  \n\nINVOICE ABC00518941 Copy\n\ABC PROJECT\n9 CHANGI SOUTH \nTAMPINES 486345 \n \n \n\nINVOICE DATE\nCUSTOMER ID\nSHIPMENT\nDUE DATE\nTERMS\nINCOTERM\n\nPage 1 of 1\n\n10-Oct-19 \nSGARSCDISIN\nSSISA017170\n09-Nov-19 \n30 days from Inv. Date\nDAP - Delivered At Place\nC06273660\n\n**Try the ABC e-Booking tool available for you through the IRIS portal** CONSOL NUMBER\n\n********************************************************************************************************************\n\nSHIPMENT DETAILS\nSHIPPER\nKUSU PTE LTD C/O ABC PTE LTD\nREFERENCE\n2500440249, 227364\nGOODS DESCRIPTION\nCABLE, 2M C14-C13 WHITE/   CABLE, 2M C14-C13 BLACK/   ROUTER, PTX1000 SYSTEM WITH 72-PORT 40G QSFP+ / 24-PORT 100G \nQSFP28 / 288-PORT 10G SFP+ WITH 4 1600W AC POWER SUPPLIES AND 3 FAN TRAYS/   INVOICE NO: 227364\nIMPORT CUSTOMS BROKER\n\nCONSIGNEE\nXYZ HONG KONG LIMITED\n\nIssued By John John@ABC.com\n\nWEIGHT\n90.000 KG\n\nVOLUME\n0.834 M3\nMAWB\n61872336191\n\nCHARGEABLE\n139.000 KG\n\nPACKAGES\n1 PLT\n\nHAWB\nSISA19017170\n\nETD 20-Sep-19\nETD 21-09-19 14:30\n\nGOODS DELIVERED TO\n\nDESTINATION\n\nETA 25-09-19 10:00\nHKHKG = Hong Kong, Hong Kong ETA 21-09-19 18:40\n\nFLIGHT / DATE\n / SQ865 / \n\nGOODS COLLECTED FROM SGSIN = Singapore , Singapore\nSGSIN = Singapore, Singapore\nORIGIN\nCHARGES\n\nDESCRIPTION\n\nFreight charge - 139 KG @ USD 0.70/KG \n\nWarehouse Handling - Gateway Fee \n\nHandling - Origin Handling \n\nDelivery Cartage \n\nDocumentation fee \n\nGST IN USD\n\nCHARGES IN USD\n\nZero Rated\n\nZero Rated\n\nZero Rated\n\nZero Rated\n\nZero Rated\n\n97.30\n\n50.00\n\n65.00\n\n75.00\n\n32.50\n\nTOTAL CHARGES\nPlease contact us within 7 days should there be any discrepancies.\n\nInterest rate of 1.5% per month will be charged on overdue invoices.\n\nNEW: Payment available via HSBC PayNow\n\nSUBTOTAL\nADD GST\n\nTOTAL USD\n\n319.80\n0.00\n\n319.80\n
```

I want to extract certain fields which signify header names and the corresponding values.

For ex:

I want (some of the fields):

```
**INVOICE** ABC00518941
**CUSTOMER ID**  SGARSCDISIN
**SHIPMENT** SSISA017170
**WEIGHT** 90.000
**VOLUME** 0.834
**CHAREGABLE** 139.00 KG
**PACKAGES** 1 PLT
**FREIGHT CHARGE** 97.30
**WAREHOUSE HANDLING- GATEWAY FEE** 50.00
**HANDLING- ORIGIN HANDLING** 65.00
**DELIVERY CHARGE** 75.00
```

Where the first field is the actual name of the field (the asterisk were used to bold it) and the value is the corresponding value of that field. Getting as list of list or list of tuples or dict is all fine as long as I can extract such pairs. I can later format them and store as columns and values.

Thanks

Comment: Only regex can't help in this case because your text string is not in actual invoice format when read in python, problem is that format is jumbled while you imported it to python. For example `INVOICE DATE\nCUSTOMER ID\nSHIPMENT` here, after INVOICE DATE the text CUSTOMER ID comes but in actual invoice it should be the actual invoice date. To read the invoice in as is format I would suggest to use Python `subprocess` module with `pdftotext`, [here](https://kaijento.github.io/2017/03/28/pdf-scraping-tim-hortons-invoice/) is an article which can help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this.I used pdfminer and textract to convert the pdf into text. Here's the complete process I used. In the original Invoice, we do have Customer ID after Invoice. I am attaching the original invoice pdf in a separate Q I asked which would give you the right context of data. Do u think there is a better way to extract text from pdf which can retain this? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108012/extracting-relevant-fields-from-pdf-file?noredirect=1#comment108108976_61108012